# Laravel systemd queue job stops, when using restart=on-failure

Tags: laravel, systemctl

We have a Laravel SystemD job for the queue, which for example sends out notification email.

Now we noticed, that the SystemD job is stopped when a email delivery did not work.

This is how our service definition looks like:

```
/etc/systemd/system # cat example.com-queue.service

[Unit]
Description=Laravel queue worker

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/example.com/web/artisan queue:work --daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The website https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart= states, that on-failure does not restart "on success".

If we look closer at the service state, we see that the Laravel Queue is actually exiting with a "0" exit code:

```
# systemctl status example.com-queue.service
● example.com-queue.service - Laravel queue worker
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/example.com-queue.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2021-08-14 15:11:18 CEST; 2 days ago
    Process: 2417820 ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/example.com/web/artisan queue:work --daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Aug 14 15:11:08 example php[2417820]: [2021-08-14 15:11:08][16768] Processing: App\Notifications\UploadSuccess
Aug 14 15:11:18 example php[2417820]: [2021-08-14 15:11:18][16768] Failed:     App\Notifications\UploadSuccess
Aug 14 15:11:18 example systemd[1]: example.com-queue.service: Succeeded.
```

There is a easy fix: We could switch to "Restart=always", but I want to shed light on the fact and find out why Laravel - in case of an error - returns a zero exit code. Also we are afraid that "Restart=always" might cause unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, I use `supervisor` to handle `queues`. However, it's very advanced, and there are many `article/support` published on its configuration, and you can find them easily.

I'm following [this supervisor configuration in the Laravel article](https://rohit-shirke.medium.com/configuring-supervisor-for-laravel-queues-81e555e550c6)

That's perfectly worked for me, and I've configured a lot of Laravel-projects `queues` by it. It also has many built-in options to handle `queue-failure`, `restarting` etc. Moreover, We can run multiple `workers` using it easily in minimum time. Its `process handling` approach is very optimized and well documented.

###### Basic Installation process:

Manage Laravel queues or any managed process which needs to be run on the server

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

load directory `cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d` and create a configuration file `my-project-worker.conf` and add the following configurations

```
[program:<custom-worker-name>]  
command=<project-directory-path>/artisan queue:work --tries=3  --sleep=3
directory=<project-directory-path i.e /var/www/html/example-project>
stdout_logfile=<custom-path-to-store-log i.e /var/www/html/example-project/storage/logs/supervisord.log>
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
stopwaitsecs=3600

## For Multiple Workers ##

[program:%(<custom-worker-name>)s_%(process_num)02d]  
command=<project-directory-path>/artisan queue:work --tries=3  --sleep=3
directory=<project-directory-path i.e /var/www/html/example-project>
stdout_logfile=<custom-path-to-store-log i.e /var/www/html/example-project/storage/logs/supervisord.log>
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=3
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

***Note:*** Make sure set `<custom-worker-name>`, `<project-directory-path>` and `<custom-path-to-store-log>` according to your project.

**Remember** that when you deploy new code which contains modifications to existing job code, you need to restart the supervisor process or that particular job.

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start <custom-worker-name>:*
```

To check running supervisor processes:

```
sudo supervisorctl
```

To check the status of the process:

```
sudo systemctl status supervisor
```

To stop the process:

```
sudo systemctl stop supervisor
```

Comment: Okay thanks, good alternative. Still I was wondering if this can be done with systemctl as well in a stable way.